# MySQL controlling shutdown

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, memory-optimized-tables

We are running a financial application using MySQL as database.

For  performance reasons  we are using memory tables for a few of our live tables where the data is populated ever few milli seconds.

To ensure data consistency in all scenarios (planned and unplanned outages)  we need to ensure that the data in the memory tables are always persisted for that  we are planning to implement shutdown hooks, wherein n case of any shutdown the data would be written in normal tables  and restored during start-up.

I am unfortunately not able to find a way to do it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

We are using MySQL ver `5.7`

Comment: Do you have a workload related benchmark that shows the memory tables actually showing a benefit compared to innodb? [because the locking granuality](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html) is at the table level. Can you show the table structure and normal set of operations on the table along with what design objectives exist?

Comment: Unfortunately would not be able to share the structure. But I can say that the table has around 30 columns and around 5000 records. The tps is around 500 (50 updates per 100ms). This is a master table which is used in joins etc with other tables. Hope this gives more data points to help us

Comment: Show the structure, with indexes. Replace the column names and in the same way in the query. If you try the same operations on innodb what throughput do you get? Otherwise I suggest getting a consultant under an NDA to entertain giving advice on less abstract facts.

Comment: From root login, from your MySQL Command Prompt, what is RESULT of  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_fast_shutdown'; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't even try.

InnoDB has years of optimization behind it.  It persists to disk even across unplanned power failures due to its integrated logs.

Furthermore, because of `MEMORY` using table locks (as opposed to InnoDB's row locks), there are benchmarks that say that InnoDB is *faster* than MEMORY.  There could be cases where Memory is faster than InnoDB.  But between your moderately high write rate and the `JOINs`, InnoDB is very likely to have less interference between the two tasks.

If you want full persistence, you need to write to the disk 500 times per second.  Are you using SSDs?  RAID?  An ordinary HDD cannot run at 500 flushes per second.  If you have a fast enough drive, you may as well let InnoDB take care of everything for you.

InnoDB's automatic saving and restoring across power failures is very likely to be faster, and much less programming effort for you.